# Why card list is not shown in a component?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ngrx

I'm new to NgRx and Firebase and I faced the issue that when card data fetched from Firestore using @ngrx/effects a list of cards is not being shown on a card-list page. But when I add new card via new-card component form, it is displayed on page, although it won't be shown on page refresh afterwards.

The interesting thing I have noticed is that when I look into Redux Dev Tool it displays card action with a data in it ([Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diOap.png)) whereas there's no any data in state. If I add a new card it has data in its state until I refresh the page. ([Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NmgK.png))

Here's my code below:

card-list.component.html

```
<mat-card id="addCard">
    <button mat-flat-button class="card__like" (click)="add()">
        <mat-icon>add_box</mat-icon>
    </button>
</mat-card>
<mat-card *ngFor="let card of cards$ | async">
    <mat-card-content>
        <span class="card__title">{{ card.title }}</span>
        <span class="card__text">{{ card.description }}</span>
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-footer>
        <button mat-flat-button class="card__edit" [routerLink]="['/info', card.id]">
            <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <button mat-flat-button class="card__like" (click)="addToFavorite(card.cardId)">
            <mat-icon [class.liked]="isLiked(card.cardId)">favorite</mat-icon>
        </button>
    </mat-card-footer>
</mat-card>
```

card-list.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, take, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { select, Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Card } from '../card';
import * as fromCard from '../store/reducer/card.reducer';
import * as actions from '../store/action/card.actions';
import * as selectors from '../store/selector/card.selectors';

import { CardService } from '../services/card.service';
import { LikeService } from '../services/like.service';
import { LoadingService } from '../services/loading.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'card-list',
  templateUrl: './card-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./card-list.component.sass'],
})
export class CardListComponent implements OnInit {
  cards: Card[] = [];

  cards$: Observable<Card[]>;

  constructor(private router: Router,
              private cardService: CardService,
              private likeService: LikeService,
              private loadingService: LoadingService,
              private afs: AngularFirestore,
              private db: AngularFireDatabase,
              private store: Store<fromCard.State>) {
    this.cards$ = this.store.select<Card[]>(selectors.selectAll).pipe(
      tap((_) => console.log(_)),
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCardsFromRealtimeDB('Descending');
  }

  ... some code

  public getCardsFromRealtimeDB(sortOrder: string) {
    this.store.dispatch(new actions.Query());
  }

  ... some code
}
```

card.effects.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, from as fromPromise } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, mergeMap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Actions, Effect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';

import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Card } from '../../models/card';
import * as cardActions from '../action/card.actions';

@Injectable()
export class CardEffects {
  @Effect()
  query$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(cardActions.QUERY),
    switchMap((action) => {
      console.log(action);
      return this.afs.collection<Card>('cards').stateChanges();
    }),
    mergeMap((actions) => actions),
    map((action) => {
      return {
        type: `[Card] ${action.type}`,
        payload: {
          id: action.payload.doc.id,
          ...action.payload.doc.data(),
        },
      };
    }),
  );

  @Effect()
  edit$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(cardActions.EDIT_CARD),
    map((action: cardActions.EditCard) => action),
    switchMap((data) => {
      const ref = this.afs.doc<Card>(`card${data.id}`);
      return fromPromise(ref.update(data.changes));
    }),
    map(() => new cardActions.Success()),
  );

  @Effect()
  delete$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(cardActions.DELETE_CARD),
    map((action: cardActions.DeleteCard) => action),
    switchMap((data) => {
      const ref = this.afs.doc<Card>(`card${data.id}`);
      return fromPromise(ref.delete());
    }),
    map(() => new cardActions.Success()),
  );

  constructor(private actions$: Actions,
              private afs: AngularFirestore) {}
}
```

card.reducer.ts

```
import { EntityState, createEntityAdapter } from '@ngrx/entity';
import * as CardActions from '../action/card.actions';
import { Card } from '../../models/card';

export const cardAdapter = createEntityAdapter<Card>();

export type Action = CardActions.All;
export interface State extends EntityState<Card> {}

export const initialState: State = cardAdapter.getInitialState();

export function cardReducer(state: State = initialState, action: Action) {
  console.log(action.type, state);

  switch (action.type) {
    case CardActions.ADD_CARD:
      return cardAdapter.addOne(action.payload, state);

    case CardActions.EDIT_CARD:
      return cardAdapter.updateOne({
        id: action.id,
        changes: action.changes,
      }, state);

    case CardActions.DELETE_CARD:
      return cardAdapter.removeOne(action.id, state);

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

card.actions.ts

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Card } from '../../models/card';

export const ADD_CARD = '[Card] Add Card';
export const GET_ALL_CARDS = '[Card] Get All Cards';
export const EDIT_CARD = '[Card] Edit Card';
export const DELETE_CARD = '[Card] Delete Card';

export const QUERY = '[Card] Query cards';

export const ADDED = '[Card] Added';
export const EDITED = '[Card] Edited';
export const DELETED = '[Card] Deleted';

export const SUCCESS = '[Card] Success';

export class AddCard implements Action {
  readonly type = ADD_CARD;

  constructor(public payload: Card) {}
}

export class GetAllCards implements Action {
  readonly type = GET_ALL_CARDS;

  constructor(public payload: Card[]) {}
}

export class EditCard implements Action {
  readonly type = EDIT_CARD;

  constructor(public id: number,
              public changes: Partial<Card>) {}
}

export class DeleteCard implements Action {
  readonly type = DELETE_CARD;

  constructor(public id: number) {}
}

export class Query implements Action {
  readonly type = QUERY;

  constructor() {}
}

export class Added implements Action {
  readonly type = ADDED;

  constructor(public payload: Card) {}
}

export class Edited implements Action {
  readonly type = EDITED;

  constructor(public payload: Card) {}
}

export class Deleted implements Action {
  readonly type = DELETED;

  constructor(public payload: Card) {}
}

export class Success implements Action {
  readonly type = SUCCESS;

  constructor() {}
}

export type All
  = AddCard
  | GetAllCards
  | EditCard
  | DeleteCard
  | Query
  | Added
  | Edited
  | Deleted
  | Success
```

Comment: Please include any further debugging steps. What does `tap((_) => console.log(_)` give you in the code above for the `cards$` observable and is this what you expect? What is the result of QUERY (why not GetAllCards?) and is this reflected in the state?

Comment: @AndrewAllen, by `tap((_) => console.log(_)` I'd like to see if there any data but I got empty array instead. GetAllCards is unused part of code I forgot to remove that could imply the same logic as Query. The Query returns card data and this data is not reflected in the state.

Comment: I cant see the action `GET_ALL_CARDS` in your reducer where you would need something like `cardAdaptor.setAll()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be missing the `GET_ALL_CARDS` action in your reducer. Something like this

**card.reducer.ts**

```
export function cardReducer(state: State = initialState, action: Action) {
  console.log(action.type, state);

  switch (action.type) {
    case CardActions.GET_ALL_CARDS:
     return cardAdaptor.setAll(action.payload, {
        ...state
       });

    case CardActions.ADD_CARD:
     return cardAdapter.addOne(action.payload, state);

    ...etc
  }
}
```